# hasNextDouble() returning false when reading from file in Java

Tags: java, file, double

I am trying to read matrix data from a file and I'm not able to figure out what is wrong. This is the code that is not working:

```
        protected static double[][] getArrayFromFile(int new_rows, int new_cols,
            String file) 
        {
        double[][] A = new double[new_rows][new_cols]; 
        try {
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(file));
            for (int i = 0; i < new_rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < new_cols; j++)
                {
                if(fileReader.hasNextDouble())
                    A[i][j] = fileReader.nextDouble();
                else
                    {
                    System.out.println("missing numbers in file");
                    break;
                    }
                }

            fileReader.close();
            }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        return A;
        }
```

This method receives a file and the number of columns and rows to be read. It is not robust
at all but it should work if you inform the parameters correctly.
After testing it and printing the matrix, I get only zeros. I am already passing the
absolute path to the data file and I'm pretty sure that the program is finding it due to 
the fact that when I pass a path that doesn't exist it shows an error message.  When running debug I see that `fileReader.hasNextDouble()`
is always returning false, so no number is getting read. Why is this happening? I have 
another method to read file from String that looks just like this and works perfectly.
Here it is:

```
protected double[][] getArrayFromString(int new_rows, int new_cols,
            String numbers)
        {
        Scanner stringReader = new Scanner(numbers);
        stringReader.useDelimiter("[^\\p{Alnum},\\.-]");

        double[][] A = new double[new_rows][new_cols]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < new_rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < new_cols; j++)
            {
            if(stringReader.hasNextDouble())
                A[i][j] = stringReader.nextDouble();
            else
                {
                stringReader.close();
                throw new RuntimeException("\n"+""
                        + "missing numbers on string");
                }
            }

        stringReader.close();
        return A;
        }
```

I've been programming for quite a while with **C** and C++ and I've just started working with JAVA, so maybe there is something stupid that I'm doing. Can anyone see the mistake I'm making?

---

EDIT

This is the file I'm trying to read:

```
 23.0       0.84825
188.5       6.87425
269.0       10.9595
321.0       13.08725
```

Comment: um.... the text file please? or at least the beginning of the file and the next 10-20 lines of data.

Comment: `hasNextDouble()` returning false means that you're not where you think you are in the file.  It's really that simple.

Comment: Scanner does NOT recognise your data as double, maybe due to Locale difference?

Comment: I set up a test program using the code, and ran it for 4 rows, 2 columns with a copy-paste of the data in the input file. It ran perfectly. This supports the Locale hypothesis.

Comment: I added this line: `fileReader.useLocale(Locale.GERMANY);` immediately after the fileReader declaration, and reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Locale suggestion seems more likely than not being where you think you are in the file, given the fact that getArrayFrom file opens the file itself.

I suggest inserting the line `fileReader.useLocale(Locale.US);` immediately after the declaration and initialization of fileReader. That forces the Locale to one in which the decimal point is ".", as required to parse your data.

Alternatively, find out what the decimal point is in the default locale and edit the text file to use that.

Comment: That solved it. I also needed to add java.util.Locale to the imported packages. Thank you all for the answers!