Scanner skipping .hasNextDouble()
I am trying to read several doubles from a file and save them in an array. The first number in the file is an integer, which should then determine the size of the array. This works. but when I try to read in the doubles afterwards, I get a false return and it skips the loop. what could be the reason for this?
This is the method I use for reading the file
public static void readFile()
{
    System.out.println("Filename (Has to be on Desktop): ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = scan.nextLine();
    String filePath = searchFileOnDesktop(fileName + ".txt");

    try
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        int arraySize = reader.nextInt();
        double[] data = new double[arraySize];
        //reader.next();
        while (reader.hasNextDouble())
        {
            int i = 0;
            data[i] = reader.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(data[i]);
            i++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

I have already tried to “reset” the reader with .next(). at least that's what I read somewhere. I can't read it in as an integer, string or whatever else there is.
This is the file I'm trying to read in:
13
5.6
6.2
6.0
5.5
5.7
6.1
7.4
5.5
5.5
6.3
6.4
4.0
6.9


Can you please [edit] your question to include a sample of the file you're trying to read?

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328022/hasnextdouble-returning-false-when-reading-from-file-in-java?

As @Martheen said, what is your system locale? Does that locale usually use . as the decimal separator?

@Martheen omg.. yes that fixed it, thanks a lot!
